# Disable an asp net Button with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, button

I have a partial view where I would like to disable a button under certain conditions.

```
<td style="padding-left: 30px;">
  <asp:Button ID="AddProdCostLine" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Add Line" CssClass="buttonBlue"></asp:Button>
</td>
```

In my javascript, I needed to check that some textboxes were filled, If not the user shouldn't be able to trigger the button (by disabling it)

In fact I need to set a textbox mandatory under the same conditions. That was my idea.
I can't find a way to disable my button here is the code :

```
function LoadComponentProdCost() {
    $(function () {
        $('input[id*="ProductionCostLineField"]').blur(function () {
            var amount = this.value;
            var textInInvoice = 'Mandatory';
            $('input[id*="ProductionCostInvoiceToLineField"]').each(function () {
                if (amount == '' || amount == '0') {
                    textInInvoice = '';
                } else {
                    textInInvoice = 'Mandatory';
                    alert("You must inform the field 'Invoiced By'");
                    //doesn't work I need here to disable the button 
                    document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").disabled = "disabled";
                    document.getElementById('<%= AddProdCostLine.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
            $('input[id*="ProductionCostInvoiceToLineField"]').val(textInInvoice);
        });
    });
```

My Javascript is in the partial view file .ascx

The rendered HTML for the component is like so :

```
<input name="ProdCostControl$ProdCostGrid$ctl02$ProductionCostInvoiceToLineField" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ProdCostControl_ProdCostGrid_ctl02_ProductionCostInvoiceToLineField" tabindex="25" style="width:269px;">
```

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");` ?

Comment: Is this function contained in an external javascript file? Meaning, outside of the VIew?

Comment: @Dario Yes I tried too and it didn't work... I'm goind to edit the post

Comment: @RyanWilson The function is within the partial view .ascx using "<script type="text/javascript">"

Comment: Please post your **rendered** HTML, both of the form HTML and the rendered strings in your `LoadComponentProdCost` function.

Comment: Your closing `</td>` is malformed. Probably not the issue, but an issue nonetheless.

Comment: @Benoît Does any of the above code execute? When does LoadComponentProdCost() get called?

Comment: @mac9416 Yes it was when I copy and paste. it is not my current code

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes everything works (I checked with alert("Message"), everything is called. Whether the "getElementById" return a null or I cant modify its property.

Comment: @Benoît I noticed your button is in a table cell, do you have this button being rendered for each row in your table?

Comment: @RyanWilson For the first row at least. But I can't trigger it yet. The button is to actually add rows :)

Comment: @Benoît Have you set a break point where you try to grab your button by id? Does it return a valid id for <%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>?

Comment: @RyanWilson How can I set a breakpoint ? The aspx page is render in Chrome, the javascript is within the page in "Element"

Comment: @Benoît use the developer tools in whichever browser you are using to test and set a break point that way.

Answer (score 0):

By using alert() function I managed to debug/check if my component was null so here is the solution to the code I post above :

```
function LoadComponentProdCost() {
    $(function () {
        $('input[id*="ProductionCostLineField"]').blur(function () {
            var amount = this.value;
            $('input[id*="ProductionCostInvoiceToLineField"]').each(function () {
                var textInvoicedBy = this.value;
                if (amount == '' || amount == '0') {
                    document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").className = 'buttonBlue';
                } else {
                    if (this.value != '' || amount == '' || amount == '0') {
                    document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").className = 'buttonBlue';
                    document.getElementById('<%= AddProdCostLine.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
                    }
                    if ((amount != '' || amount != '0') && textInvoicedBy == '') {
                        alert("You must inform the field 'Invoiced By'");
                        document.getElementById("<%=AddProdCostLine.ClientID%>").className = 'buttonLightGray3';
                        document.getElementById('<%= AddProdCostLine.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```